# How do I get identical results from the old hist and the new histcounts functions in Matlab

Tags: matlab, histogram, binning

I am trying to replace a use of the old hist function by the new histcounts which performs faster at binning and counting than hist. However, I am struggling to achieve the exact same results from histcounts that I got from hist.

I am aware that histcounts returns the bin edges rather than the binCenters. However, the counts should be identical and the bin edges should be convertible to bin centers, as far as I understand.

The Matlab reference page for replacing hist with histcounts (see http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/replace-discouraged-instances-of-hist-and-histc.html) does not touch upon this inequality of results and only converts binCenters to binEdges (not the other way around)

This small piece of code helps to illustrate my problem.

```
A = randn(100,2);

[N1,binCenters1] = hist(A(:,1),10);
[N2,binEdges2] = histcounts(A(:,1),10);

binCenters2 = mean([binEdges2(1:end-1);binEdges2(2:end)]);

N = [N1;N2;abs(N1-N2)];
binCenters = [binCenters1;binCenters2;abs(binCenters1-binCenters2)];
```

It outputs

N:

```
1   2   4   7   28  28  16  8   4   2
1   0   5   6   23  34  15  10  4   2
0   2   1   1   5   6   1   2   0   0
```

binCenters:

```
-2,46697043006437   -1,93055060769862   -1,39413078533287   -0,857710962967123  -0,321291140601375  0,215128681764373   0,751548504130121   1,28796832649587    1,82438814886162    2,36080797122737
-2,71500000000000   -2,14500000000000   -1,57500000000000   -1,00500000000000   -0,435000000000000  0,135000000000000   0,705000000000000   1,27500000000000    1,84500000000000    2,41500000000000
0,248029569935633   0,214449392301381   0,180869214667129   0,147289037032877   0,113708859398625   0,0801286817643727  0,0465485041301204  0,0129683264958687  0,0206118511383833  0,0541920287726354
```

As you can see, the difference is nonzero.

Comment: That's because your formula to convert binEdges to binCenters is wrong, check that [How to convert bin edge to bin center](http://www.mathworks.com/examples/matlab/mw/matlab-ex22718103-convert-bin-centers-to-bin-edges)

Comment: Okay, let's consider that fixed then. This still leaves the problem of the counts (N variable) being different as that is a direct output of the hist and histcounts functions.