# What is the automatic binning algorithm used in MATLAB's histogram function?

Tags: matlab, histogram, binning

An automatic binning algorithm was used in the default bin selection of the `histogram` function in MATLAB. On the documentation however, there is no mention of the reference material/publication used for implementing this. What is this algorithm?

Comment: You are right, the default binning method is not specified in the documentation. It is likely a proprietary heuristic that selects 'scott', 'fd' or 'integers' based on data properties. One thing you can do is click on the "No" button at the bottom of the documentation page (where it says "Was this topic helpful?") and give as feedback that there is no explanation of the 'BinMethod'='auto' method. You might get lucky and learn something. :)

Comment: Thank you @Cris Luengo. I actually did that yesterday and i'm hoping they give a positive response.

Comment: Please post the reply here as an answer if you get one. I'd be curious to hear!

Comment: No worries at all. I will do so.

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](https://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/hist.html) says:

> `hist(x)` creates a histogram bar chart of the elements in vector x. The elements in x are sorted into 10 equally spaced bins along the x-axis between the minimum and maximum values of x.

So if we assume that `x` is sorted then the bounds of the bins are given by the vector

```
 x(1) + (1:9)./10 * (x(end)-x(1))
```

Comment: Thank you @flawr. Actually, i understand that the hist() function uses a default of 10 bins. If you read the documentation on histogram(), you'll notice they mentioned this automatic binning algorithm. However, they didn't state the reference like they do in some other functions at the end of the documentation.

Comment: flawr and @CrisLuengo [It seems that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38263792/how-do-i-get-identical-results-from-the-old-hist-and-the-new-histcounts-function) `hist` and `histogram` don't use the same algorithm.

Comment: @rahnema1: you are right, the new `histogram` is quite the improvement. I hadn't paid much attention to it yet.